How can I use large assets folder in tauri with react?
I am creating a project through tauri and react to display images and videos in high definition. I would like to embed the folder with all the assets with the project (about 4 gb).
I tried putting the folder directly into the "public" folder but tauri can't make the build of the app.
I would like to use the best solution in terms of performance because since the images and videos are very large I need to be able to view them without lag.
Are there any other ways? Where is it best to place the folder?
I tried moving the folder and embedding it as a folder to add to the build but then I didn't quite understand how to access the asset from the frontend.
error "npn run tauri build"
LLVM ERROR: out of memory                                                                                             
Allocation failed
error: could not compile `app` (bin "app")

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name app --edition=2021 src\main.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --diagnostic-width=117 --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no --cfg "feature=\"custom-protocol\"" -C metadata=9e02e08eb434a29b --out-dir
...
L native=C:\Users\lucas\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\windows_x86_64_msvc-0.39.0\lib --cfg desktop` (exit code: 0xc0000409, STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN)
       Error failed to build app: failed to build app


"but tauri can't make the build of the app" How so? Any errors, please [edit] your question to include any errors!

its an out of memory error, he use all my 32 gb of ram and after 15 min he get the error

Embedding is the answer, as youve already discovered. However since this is a large file you cant just use the JS FS API to read the file in one go as it would be in memory in the browser and the memory usage would be huge. Actually this is tricky in tauri sadly. You have to build a special HTTP server with HTTP Range support in the Rust backend. https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/4133 very relevant. And implementation here https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/tree/dev/examples/streaming is 90% what you need (you dont need to to download the video from somewhere, you already have it)

However, I wonder about your use case. Embedding things this size in a desktop application is going to make your app download huge. The user would need to download every video, even if they dont watch any or watch just one!! You shouldn't be looking to build these in your app at all. Instead, host them elsewhere. Easiest way would be on a Video CDN (google it, theres thousands). Then simply link to that. Its not scalable to be building them into the actual app and doesnt make architectural sense. 4gb is already way past the reasonable threshold.

Of course, it costs bandwidth to host. But it would be even worse if they had to download every single video all at once to get the app in the first place!

thank you, this is an application for a client and it has to be installed on one pc. it is mainly for making presentations and showing photos and videos so i am looking for the fastest and most performant solution to be able to do it. i am coming from the web dev so i was hoping tauri could be a good solution but i guess for this application it is not the best .
